# UIPickerView is slow at updating

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an app that loads the UIPickerView options from an online JSON file, while it is able to successfully do it, it is extremely slow, and I'm wondering why. The console prints the JSON file in 2 seconds but it likes 12 more seconds to appear in the picker view unless I manually move it. How can I get the PickerView to load the options faster without having to manually move it to show the options?

Here is the part of my code:

```
import UIKit
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var mypickerview: UIPickerView!
var pickerData: [String] = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

/*Begin Loading the list*/
let postEndpoint: String = "https://example.com/json.json"
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!
session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
print("Not a 200 response")
return
}
do {
if let ipString = NSString(data:data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
print(ipString)
let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

let One = jsonDictionary["One"] as! String
let Two = jsonDictionary["Two"] as! String
let Three = jsonDictionary["Three"] as! String
let Four = jsonDictionary["Four"] as! String

self.mypickerview.delegate = self
self.mypickerview.dataSource = self
self.pickerData = [One, Two, Three, Four]
self.mypickerview.reloadAllComponents()
self.mypickerview.delegate = self;

}
} catch {
print("bad things happened")
}
}).resume()
/*End Loading the list*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must call `ReloadAllcompenents()` always on the main queue cause it will update your view . dispatch_async should resolve the problem . hope it help

```
  let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.mypickerview.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it for me! Will update the bounty in 22 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You're reloading the picker on a background queue. Big delays on UI changes are a common symptom of this. You need to dispatch the UI work (anything involving the picker) to the main queue.

Completion handlers for URL session tasks are called on the delegate queue for the session, which is not the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

`Dispatch.main.async` - Update the `pickerView` on the `MAIN queue`.

In my experience doing `watchos`, whenever I updated UI in `sessionDataTask` completionBlock, it was SLOW until I did it on the main queue.

In other words, you can create the `sessionDataTask` on any thread or queue, but within the completionBlock, dispatch it on the main queue/thread. You should always update UI on the mainQueue.

```
let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        if let ipString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            if let jsonDictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) {

                DispatchQueue.main.async { //dispatch_async on MainQueue.

                    let One = jsonDictionary["One"] as! String
                    let Two = jsonDictionary["Two"] as! String
                    let Three = jsonDictionary["Three"] as! String
                    let Four = jsonDictionary["Four"] as! String

                    self.mypickerview.delegate = self
                    self.mypickerview.dataSource = self
                    self.pickerData = [One, Two, Three, Four]
                    self.mypickerview.reloadAllComponents()

                }
            }
        }
    }
```